# Trouble with IO objects Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, io, rendering, gloss

For uni I have this project where i need to program a simple game in haskell. Right now I'm facing the following problem:

```
instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer pos rad bults _) = do playerpic  <- displayimg pos rad "./images/player.bmp"
                                         bulletpics <- ...
                                         return $ pictures (playerpic:bulletpics)
```

at the `...` i need a function `f :: [Bullet] -> IO [Picture]`

where the function producing a picture for the bullet object is :

```
render :: Bullet -> IO Picture
```

is there a way to create the function I need. I've been toying around on paper with monads and functors but cannot find a way to get this done. Any help at all with this is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Let me Hoogle this for you](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28bullet+-%3E+IO+picture%29+-%3E+%5Bbullet%5D+-%3E+IO+%5Bpicture%5D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) for this:

```
instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer pos rad bults _) = do
    playerpic  <- displayimg pos rad "./images/player.bmp"
    bulletpics <- mapM render bults
    return $ pictures (playerpic:bulletpics)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`. In your code that looks like this:

```
instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer pos rad bults _) = do playerpic  <- displayimg pos rad "./images/player.bmp"
                                         bulletpics <- traverse render bults
                                         return $ pictures (playerpic:bulletpics)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `do` notation solutions provided are quite normal, and easy for a beginner to understand. But with more experience, you might also consider using applicative style, to make it clearer (to both the reader and the compiler) that the handling of the player and the bullets are independent:

```
instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer pos rad bults _) = liftA2 go
      (displayimg pos rad "./images/player.bmp") 
      (traverse render bults)
    where go playerpic bulletpics = pictures $ playerpic : bulletpics
```